# Create jquery modal dialog dynamically

Tags: jquery, dialog, modal-dialog

i want to create a jquery dialog modal dynamically when runing my page, but i can't get it **modal**, i get a no modal dialog

that is my simple code

```
        <script>
            function show() {
                var dialog = $('<div id="msg_dialog"></div>').dialog();
                dialog.dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    autoOpen: true,
                    title: 'Test',
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            text: 'Ok', 
                            click: function() {
                                $('#res').empty().append('<h1>Open<h1>');
                                $('#msg_dialog').remove();
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Cancel',
                            click: function() {
                                $('#res').empty().append('<h1>Close<h1>');
                                $('#msg_dialog').remove();
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Load Modal onload**
Make sure you run the function on load.
Try this code :
Replace `<body>` with

```
<body onload="show();">
```

Or else you can add this line

```
window.onload = function(){show();};
```

**SIMPLE MODAL CODE TO HELP YOU CORRECT YOUR CODE**

```
$("#dialog-message").dialog({
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    position: ['center', 'top'],
    show: 'blind',
    hide: 'blind',
    width: 400,
    dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
    buttons: {
        "I've read and understand this": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Source : http://jsfiddle.net/db5SX/

Comment: i have it like that 
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="show()" value="show" />
<div id="res"></div>
</body>

Comment: @Zouhair See updated answer , your code loads modal onclick.
If you provide a jsfiddle your question will be easy to understand.

Comment: thx Avadhesh18, i can't get a modal dialog, i get a no modal dialog, the issu , how i can get a **modal** dialog dynamically

Comment: @Zouhair see updated answer this might help you to correct your code.

Comment: sorry, i have tryed it, but i can get a modal dialog :(

Comment: some confusion is at stake here, what is in your fiddle is a modal dialog, check here http://jsfiddle.net/db5SX/2546/ try clicking a button, you can't 'cause its modal. Try clicking here http://jsfiddle.net/db5SX/2545/ its possible, 'cause its not modal